# Preventing Python webbrowser.open() from dominating screen and preventing other processes. Is it possible to open as minimised?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, browser, webbrowser-control

I am using webbroswer.open() in a loop to download multiple files at given intervals.

The issue I am having is that whenever the browser window opens, it becomes the primary window and thereby interrupts and disrupts my ability to use the computer. Downloading multiple files means this can last some time. The broswer continuously flashing open is obviously jarring.

Is there any way to instruct webbrowser to open the browser minimised by default or otherwise avoid this issue in some other ingenious way?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using other modules I would urge you to look into `selenium`. This allows you to do many things, and one of them is to launch in headless mode (so as not to disturb you as it loads pages). The documentation is at:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

And you would be interested in the headless option

You would be advised though to make sure your script works without this enabled before you enable it though.

Sample code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

my_options = Options()
my_options.headless = True # set to False for debugging!!

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=my_options)
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print('Done.')
```

You will need to download the proper drivers (just follow the instructions on the link I posted) for whatever browser you'd like. I picked Chrome, but they have Edge, Firefox, and Safari browsers as well!